# Error: unsupported format string passed to list.__format__

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to print the return from a function but I get this error message:

```
unsupported format string passed to list.__format__
```

Here is the function:

```
def award_list(arr, threshold): 
    awards = []
    for i in arr:
        if i >= threshold:
            awards.append(i)
    return awards
```

And here is the print statement:

```
print('These divisions get an award:'+format(award_list(sales_list, threshold), '.2f'))
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error message or what it means.

Answer (score 2):

A `list` does not support such formatting simply because it is a list, not a number. If you need to format a list with specific style, you would use

```
result = award_list(sales_list, threshold)
message = ','.join(['{:.2f}'.format(x) for x in result])
print('These divisions get an award: ' + message)
```

this code applies formatting on each element and then combines resulting strings into one (separated by comma). Or if you prefer using `format`

```
message = ','.join([format(x, '.2f') for x in result])
```